# Spree vs Solidus for Shopify like application

Tags: ecommerce, ruby-on-rails

We are building a multi-tenant SaaS application where our users can easily build e-commerce sites of their own; very similar to what Shopify offers, except that this will be tailored to a specific kind of goods industry - custom integrations with industry partners, integrations with our users' company CRM systems, etc.

Examples of customisations:

- A single admin should be able to manage multiple stores
- Obviously, like Shopify, each store would have its own set of users / customers and subdomain
- The order processing mechanism should be different for each store - store A might need to call an external API to place the order while store B might just need to add an entry in a spreadsheet.

Within our team, we have extensive Ruby on Rails experience, so I think going with [Spree](https://spreecommerce.org) or [Solidus](https://solidus.io) is the way forward.

But we are finding it hard to choose between one over the other as this will be a long term investment.

Does anybody have enough experience with both of them to be able to objectively compare?